# how to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \int_0^x \frac{\sin^2(u)}{\sin(x^3)}du $

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

How to find
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \int_0^x \frac{\sin^2(u)}{\sin(x^3)}du ?
$$
Where should I even start with this one? Can I pull out $\frac{1}{\sin(x^3)}$ outside the integral as $x$ is an constant and we're finding integral with respect to to $u$?, and then apply Leibniz integral rule?

*Where should I even get started with this one its kinda confusing.*

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what happens when you pull the $1/\sin(x^3)$-term out. I mean, first see what happens, and *then* ask if it is valid.

Comment: Please proceed by taking $\sin x^3$ out of the integral sign. Can you evaluate the integral after that? Also please update your post with your attempt based on this.

Comment: @TobyMak: that does not matter. The variable of integration is $u$. Other variables need to be treated as constant as far process of integration is concerned.

Comment: Also are you aware of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? That can be used here to get the answer directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sin(x^3)} \int_0^x \sin^2 u \ du \right)$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(  \frac{1}{\sin(x^3)} \left[\frac{1}{2}u - \frac{1}{4} \sin2u \right]_0^x \right)$$

and when $x^3$ is small, $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ and $\sin x^3 \approx x^3$, so:

> $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^3} \left[\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4} \sin(2x) \right] \right)$$
>  $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^3} \left[\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{4} (2x - 8x^3/6) \right] \right)$$
>  $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^3} (2x^3/6)  \right) =\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Please engage with the asker via comments to improve their question instead of answering. You may also have a look at the guidelines discussed in [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: I am fully aware of the post you have linked. The OP has shown enough of a try in my opinion to be worth answering, and the quality standards are subjective and should be applied case-by-case. I can't just answer: "yes, your idea is correct" as comments belong in the comments section.

Comment: Enough of a try is probably evaluating the integral. But I respect your opinion here and hope you will respect mine as well.

Comment: @TobyMak this might sound stupid to ask but how did you got sin(2x) = 2x-8x^3/6?. i'm new to this stuff but isnt sin(2x) = 2sinxcosx?

Comment: The key part is when $x$ is small i.e $\lim_{x \to 0}$. $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ from the Taylor series, and now replace $x$ with $2u$.